# Bind Generic list to entity inside enity

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

This is the model I have which I am binding data to it using linq

```
public class Physician
 {
    public Physician()
    {
        PhysicianAddress = new Address();
    }      
    public int PhysicianId { get; set; } 
    public string NPI { get; set; }
    public string PhysicianPrefixName { get; set; }  
    public string PhysicianFirstName { get; set; }        
    public string PhysicianMiddleName { get; set; }        
    public string PhysicianLastName { get; set; }         
    public string PhysicianPhoneExt { get; set; }        
    public string PhysicianPhoneNum { get; set; }        
    public string PhysicianFaxNum { get; set; }        
    public string PhysicianEmailAddr { get; set; }        
    public string PhysicianComment { get; set; }        
    public List<Site> PracticeLocationsList { get; set; }        
    public Address PhysicianAddress { get; set; }        
    public int? MergedIntoPhysicianId { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting data from storedProcedure and then I am binding the return result to model

```
   var physicians = (from sp in e.GetSitePhysicians((int)request.SiteId)
                              select new Physician()
                              {
                                  PhysicianId = sp.PhysicianId,
                                  PhysicianFirstName = sp.PhysicianFirstName,
                                  PhysicianMiddleName = sp.PhysicianMiddleName,
                                  PhysicianLastName = sp.PhysicianLastName,
                                  NPI = sp.NPI,
                                  PhysicianPhoneNum = sp.PhysicianPhoneNum,
                                  PhysicianFaxNum = sp.PhysicianFaxNum,
                                  PhysicianEndDate = sp.PhysicianEndDate,
                                  PhysicianEffectiveDate = sp.PhysicianEffectiveDate,
                                  PhysicianComment = sp.PhysicianComment,
                                  AddressId = sp.AddressId,
                                  PhysicianEmailAddr = sp.PhysicianEmailAddr,
                                  PhysicianPhoneExt = sp.PhysicianPhoneExt,
                                  PhysicianAddress = new Address()
                                  {
                                      SiteAddressId =  sp.SiteAddressId ?? 0,
                                      Street1 =  sp.SiteAddressStreet1 ?? string.Empty,
                                      Street2 = sp.SiteAddressStreet2 ?? string.Empty,
                                      City = sp.SiteAddressCityName ?? string.Empty,
                                      PostalCode = sp.SiteAddressPostalCode ?? string.Empty,
                                      State =  sp.GeographicalStateProvinceCode ?? string.Empty,
                                      ParkingInstructions =  sp.SiteAddressParkingInstructions ?? string.Empty,
                                  },
                                  PracticeLocationsList=new Site()
                                            {
                                                Id = sp.SiteId,
                                                Name = sp.SiteName,
                                                SiteMainPhoneNum = sp.SiteMainPhoneNum,
                                                Address = new Address
                                                {
                                                    SiteAddressId = sp.SiteAddressId??0,
                                                    Street1 = sp.SiteAddressStreet1,
                                                    Street2 = sp.SiteAddressStreet2,
                                                    City = sp.SiteAddressCityName,
                                                    PostalCode = sp.SiteAddressPostalCode,
                                                    State = sp.GeographicalStateProvinceCode
                                                },
                                                Contacts = new    List<SiteContact>() { new SiteContact() }
                                            }
                              }).ToList();
```

When I try to bind my Site Object to PracticeLocationsList it is generating compile time error that "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Site' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'".

How to convert my Site Object to List and then bind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are trying to assign one object to a list.

Try this:

```
PracticeLocationsList = new List<Site> { new Site()...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `PracticeLocationsList` can be assigned to a `List<Site>`, what about this:

```
 PracticeLocationsList= new List<Site>()
                                     { new Site()
                                        {
                                            Id = sp.SiteId,
                                            Name = sp.SiteName,
                                            SiteMainPhoneNum = sp.SiteMainPhoneNum,
                                            Address = new Address
                                            {
                                                SiteAddressId = sp.SiteAddressId??0,
                                                Street1 = sp.SiteAddressStreet1,
                                                Street2 = sp.SiteAddressStreet2,
                                                City = sp.SiteAddressCityName,
                                                PostalCode = sp.SiteAddressPostalCode,
                                                State = sp.GeographicalStateProvinceCode
                                            },
                                            Contacts = new    List<SiteContact>() { new SiteContact() }
                                        }
                                     }
```